# How to change the export community page name?

Tags: lightning-community

We have exported the community page and added into the package.
for example the community page name is **AccountPage** and it's added into package.[image]
Now I want to rename it like to change **AccountPage** to **MasterAccountPage**.

*Is there any Possible way to rename the exported community page after we have packaged.*